# How to maintain the state in timer start/stop in listview flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried to implement the timer in my list view of the card. Each card should contain a start/stop button with the timer field. When I start the timer and it starts running "00:03"... The timer should run on all the cards.

[image]

Comment: did you try to set `addAutomaticKeepAlives ` on listview?

Comment: In what boolean value i want to set in the addAutomaticKeepAlives?

Comment: Sorry my confusion. Try wrapping your nodes into a `KeepAlive`. You can also try `KeepAliveNotification`

Comment: I got a reference from the link https://github.com/bizz84/stopwatch-flutter/blob/master/lib/timer_page.dart